# I am trying to webscrape basketball reference, and I am using proxy networks to avoid error 429, but I it keeps giving an error

Tags: python, web-scraping, statsmodels

Here's an example of what I am trying to do, a code that works but does not rotate proxies:

```
link = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/NOP/2023.html#advanced'
dfs = pd.read_html(link)
stats = dfs[1].dropna()
d = stats.to_dict('records')
```

This is me trying to rotate proxies, but it doesn't work:

```
link = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/NOP/2023.html#advanced'
page = requests.get(link, proxies = {'http://': temp, 'https://':temp}, timeout = 5).text
dfs = pd.read_csv(StringIO(page),error_bad_lines=False)
```

Any advice or quick fixes here?

Answer (score 3):

It's not immediately clear from your code what problem you're having.

I quickly threw together this working example.  Maybe it'll help?

**Notes:**

1. I'm splitting each proxy string by ":" to extract host, port,
   username, and password from each and creating a HTTPProxyAuth object
   from them, but you can skip passing auth if your proxies dont need
   it.
2. I couldn't get results with dfs = pd.read_csv(page) so I swapped it
   out for read_html instead.

```
        import requests
        from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
        import pandas as pd
        
        proxies = [  'proxy1:port:username:password',
                     'proxy2:port:username:password',
                     'proxy3:port:username:password',
                     # add more proxies as needed
                   ]
        
        link = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/teams/NOP/2023.html#advanced'
        success = False
        for proxy_str in proxies:
            try:
                host, port, username, password = proxy_str.split(':')
                proxy = {
                    'http': f'http://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}',
                    'https': f'https://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}'
                }
                # Use this instead if proxies dont need auth
                # host, port = proxy_str.split(':')
                # proxy = {
                #    'http': f'http://{host}:{port}',
                #    'https': f'https://{host}:{port}'
                # }
                
                auth = HTTPProxyAuth(username, password) # remove if proxies dont need auth
                
                page = requests.get(link, proxies=proxy, timeout=5, auth=auth).text
                dfs = pd.read_html(page)
                stats = dfs[1].dropna()
                d = stats.to_dict('records')
                print(d) # show results
                success = True
                break
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")
  if not success:
        print("All proxies failed.")
```

This gets me 15 players' stats (printing the variable 'd') like this, which I assume is what you want.

```
[
{
    'Rk': 1,
    'Player': 'CJ McCollum',
    'Age': 31,
    'G': 62,
    'GS': 62,
    'MP': 35.0,
    'FG': 7.9,
    'FGA': 18.2,
    'FG%': 0.434,
    '3P': 2.8,
    '3PA': 7.4,
    '3P%': 0.379,
    '2P': 5.1,
    '2PA': 10.8,
    '2P%': 0.472,
    'eFG%': 0.511,
    'FT': 2.5,
    'FTA': 3.2,
    'FT%': 0.789,
    'ORB': 0.8,
    'DRB': 3.5,
    'TRB': 4.4,
    'AST': 6.0,
    'STL': 0.9,
    'BLK': 0.5,
    'TOV': 2.6,
    'PF': 2.0,
    'PTS': 21.1
  },
  #...14 more
 ]
```

For the proxies themselves I'm assuming you have your own, just know that using premium residential proxies [like these](https://get.brightdata.com/bd-residential-proxies) will give you consistent results over free ones from geonode or similar.